# Subtrair data de um DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, data

Estou precisando pegar data atual e subtrair 3 meses.

Estrou fazendo conversões e subtraindo 3 mas vai dar errado ao virar o ano, em janeiro por exemplo ira resultar em mês -2.

Creio que haja uma forma mais adequada de fazer esse procedimento.

Comment: Agora deu certo, estou me familiarizado com a plataforma. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe um modo mais adequado. A estrutura `DateTime` tem o método [**`AddMonths`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx), para subtrair uma quantidade de números é usar este método com um parâmetro negativo.

Por exemplo

```
var data = new DateTime(2017, 01, 01);
var novaData = data.AddMonths(-3);
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vZHFpR)</sup>

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.